# Collectors.toMap only if optional value is present

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type, collectors

I have a list of languages like english, french, etc. I also have a list of words like apple, orange, etc. For each word, I want to create a map that looks like this:

Map map = {english = apple, italian = mela}

In order to get the translatedWord, I have a function that returns an optional. Signature of the method looks like this:

> `Optional<TranslatedWord> getTranslatedWord(String word, Language language);`

This is the code I have written to collect the words into a map

```
List<Language> languages = {english, italian, french};
for(String w : words) {
   Map<Language, TranslatedWord> map = languages.stream().collect(Collectors.ToMap(language -> language,
      language -> getTranslatedWord(w, language));

   doSomethingWithThisMap(map);
}
```

The problem is getTranslatedWord() returns an Optional. I need to collect it into the Map only if the optional has a value in it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filter before you collect:

```
Map<Language, TranslatedWord> map =
    languages.stream()
        .map(lang -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(lang, getTranslatedWord(w, lang)))
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().isPresent())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().get()));
```

However, streams don't add all that much value here. You could just use a loop:

```
Map<Language, TranslatedWord> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Language lang : languages) {
  getTranslatedWord(w, lang)
      .ifPresent(t -> map.put(lang, t));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put a filter before collecting into map

```
    for(String w : words) {
        Map<Language, TranslatedWord> map = languages.stream()
                .map(lang -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(lang, getTranslatedWord(w, lang)))
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().isPresent())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue().get()));

       doSomethingWithThisMap(map);
    }
```

Comment: The immediate concern that arises here is that `getTranslatedWord` is called twice in a single pipeline.

Comment: yes. that's very valid concern. I think the other answer by @Andy Terner is nice who is maping the data before filtering.